# Roots of a canonical line bundle on a compact Riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, fiber-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Suppose we have a compact Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g$.  Let $K$ denote the canonical line bundle on $X$, it's well known that $deg\ K=2g-2$.  A square root of $K$ by definition is a  holomorphic line $L$ bundle that satisfies $L\otimes L=K$. Then are $2^{2g}$ different square roots, e.g. see [this link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Theta+characteristic) .

Now suppose $m$ is an integer such that $m$ divides $deg\ K=2g-2$. Let's call a holomorphic line bundle $L$ for which $L^{\otimes m}=K$, an $m$-root of $K$. Is true in general that they are $m^{2g}$ different holomorphic  $m$-roots?

Comment: Yes, the number of different n-roots are just the number of n-torsion points of its albanese variety.

Comment: @ChenJiang Could you give some references, please?

Comment: Would love to see some references for this as well!